# MediaRecorder - setOrientationHint() exception/fail

Tags: java, android, video, mediarecorder

I've been trying to fix this problem with `MediaRecorder` video Rotation on and off for weeks. I cannot get the line `setOrientationHint(90)` to work on a physical Samsung Galaxy S1 running `Android 2.3.3` (`SDK 10`). This should run fine on anything above `SDK 9`.

When I call `setOrientationHint(90)` I get an exception : `setParameters(video-param-rotation-angle-degrees=90) failed`. Detailed error details below.

As a result I'm forced to check SDK and only call `setOrientationHint()` if SDK>10. ie, this code works fine on all other SDK versions above 10 which I have tested. I have tested on Samsung Galaxy Nexus running `4.2.2` and works fine.

Here is my code: 
(cut down to show order of calls to `MediaRecorder`)

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance();

mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

// Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

// Step 2: Set sources
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

// Step 3: recording setup
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720,480);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

// Step 4: Set output file
currentOutputFileName = DIRECTORY_PATH + "zzzz"+ iCount +".mp4";
mFile = new File(currentOutputFileName);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

// Step 4.1: Set recording length
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);

// Step 5: Set the preview output
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraView.getHolder().getSurface());

// Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Has anyone had this problem? I can't find anyone else is experiencing this and I can't believe thats the case. Is it possible its just a Australian Samsung Galaxy S1 running 2.3.3 issue?

I've seen references to people having problems where that line runs but with the actual video does not rotate but I actually receive an Exception - the line doesn't run at all. I've checked and rechecked the command order and it seems fine. I think what is most important is that the `setOrientationHint()` command occurs before `mediaRecorder.prepare()`

Here is the Error:

```
AuthorDriver::setParameter() unrecognized key "video-param-rotation-angle-degrees"
setParameter(video-param-rotation-angle-degrees = 90) failed with result -5
Ln 1047 handleSetParameters("video-param-rotation-angle-degrees=90") error
Command (12) failed
setParameters(video-param-rotation-angle-degrees=90) failed: -2147483648
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameter failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setParameter(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(MediaRecorder.java:341)
    at com.on3x.emergency.Recorder.prepareVideoRecorder(Recorder.java:196)
    at com.on3x.emergency.Recorder.startRecording(Recorder.java:90)
    at com.on3x.emergency.GUI.RecordActivity$1.onClick(RecordActivity.java:86)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.on3x.emergency/.GUI.RecordActivity
Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

If anyone can give ANY help it would be much appreciated. For now I've had to tell our client that its not something I can fix at this moment and Video will have to be sideways.

Is there another way of rotating videos? Basically my app records videos and uploads them to the server. At the moment this 2.3.3 phone cannot rotate the video so its uploaded sideways

Cheers

**Edit:**
This is the code I now have in place. As suggested by Ashish Gupta, AuthorDriver does not contain the appropriate param on Samsung Galaxy S1 (australian model) running 2.3.3

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=9) {

    // attempt to rotate the video 90 degrees. 
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        Utils.logLine("orientation rotated 90", this, Utils.LOG_TYPE_DEBUG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.logLine("error trying setOrientationHint"+ e.getMessage(), this, Utils.LOG_TYPE_ERROR, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
} else {
    Utils.logLine("orientation set skipped ", this, Utils.LOG_TYPE_DEBUG);
}
```

Note: Utils.logLine is simply a Utilility function I have for printing debug and error statements to log. Hopefully that might help someone else...

Comment: Does `setOrientationHint()` work with any of the allowed values on 2.3.3? In the Error you have attached `setParameters(video-param-rotation-angle-degrees=180)` it seems you are trying to set 180 instead of 90. Is that correct? Also, what is the default locale set on the device?

Comment: Oops ignore that it says 180, I was temporarily testing 180 to see if it was only 90 which was the problem. Error is  updated. What did you mean does it work with Allowed values? I just assumed it should at least work with 90, because I've seen many people using that in example code. I actually don't have a Locale set, is there a requirement to do so? I've not previously come across one. Cheers

Comment: All I want to know is whether this particular API is working with any of the allowed values (0, 90, 180, 270). There might be an issue with the default locale set on the device when you are recording the video. Look at [this](http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=android/platform/frameworks/base.git;a=commitdiff;h=2450830c0c41a45d333838f4dcf3ba1e4a2409a2) link. This could be the one causing issue.

Comment: Also enable Verbose Logging in your `Logcat` and attach the logs here.

Comment: 1) Regarding Verbose logcat, the above error logs are the errors from verbose logcat already, 2) I've tried all variables (0,90,180 etc) they all receive that error. 3) I'm going to see if setting a locale helps

Comment: I am looking for a specific log in `Logcat`. Something like `setParameters: video-param-rotation-angle-degrees=`. if you do not see this in the verbose logs, try selecting "All messages (no filters)". Also, set the locale of the device to US English and see if it works.

Comment: Geez, learn something everyday, I think it was auto selecting my App in Logcat, when i Selected "All messages" i see more detail. I've not yet put in locale doing now... updated errors for now.

Comment: `unrecognized key "video-param-rotation-angle-degrees"` is interesting, along with `setParameter(video-param-rotation-angle-degrees = 90) failed with result -5`

Comment: Ok unfortunately no difference after setting locale to US. also i can't believe i can't find any reference to `unrecognized key "video-param-rotation-angle-degrees`. Thanks for your help btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the logs you have attached, it seems that Samsung Galaxy S1 running `Android 2.3.3` does not support `setOrientationHint`.
This is the code from AuthorDriver.cpp

```
PVMFStatus AuthorDriver::setParameter(
    const String8& key, const String8& value) {
if (key == "max-duration") {
    int64_t max_duration_ms;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &max_duration_ms)) {
        return setMaxDurationOrFileSize(
                max_duration_ms, true /* limit_is_duration */);
    }
} else if (key == "max-filesize") {
    int64_t max_filesize_bytes;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &max_filesize_bytes)) {
        return setMaxDurationOrFileSize(
                max_filesize_bytes, false /* limit is filesize */);
    }
} else if (key == "audio-param-sampling-rate") {
    int64_t sampling_rate;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &sampling_rate)) {
        return setParamAudioSamplingRate(sampling_rate);
    }
} else if (key == "audio-param-number-of-channels") {
    int64_t number_of_channels;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &number_of_channels)) {
        return setParamAudioNumberOfChannels(number_of_channels);
    }
} else if (key == "audio-param-encoding-bitrate") {
    int64_t audio_bitrate;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &audio_bitrate)) {
        return setParamAudioEncodingBitrate(audio_bitrate);
    }
} else if (key == "video-param-encoding-bitrate") {
    int64_t video_bitrate;
    if (safe_strtoi64(value.string(), &video_bitrate)) {
        return setParamVideoEncodingBitrate(video_bitrate);
    }
}

// Return error if the key wasnt found
LOGE("AuthorDriver::setParameter() unrecognized key \"%s\"", key.string());
return PVMFErrArgument;
}
```

The key `video-param-rotation-angle-degrees` is not supported on Samsung Galaxy S1 aith Android 2.3.3

You can compare the logs between Nexus 4.2.2 and S1 2.3.3 and see if you see any noticeable difference.

Comment: Mate, thats great help. Where can I get hold of that file to compare with the file from my Galaxy Nexus? its running 4.2.2. Basically though, the code works perfectly on my Galaxy Nexus so I currently have an `IF` statement simply saying if < version 10, then don't use setOrientationHint() but this then breaks all devices above 8 obviously. Because previously I thought this was a generic with all 2.3.3 but seems its constrained to AU Samsung galaxy S1. I just need to check for the key `video-param-rotation-angle-degrees` if it exists. but not sure how to check for that. great help thank you.

Comment: that makes perfect sense now... our client is running a device with 2.3.3 and they mentioned the problem with screen rotation is ok. but i forgot i had the IF statement disabling `setOrientationHint()` across the board for 2.3.3 devices. I bet if i re-enabled it this would work for them because they aren't using galaxy S1 they're using some other device. I'll put the line back in but just put a try/catch around it until i can determine categorically what key's are available in Authordriver from the specifica device.

Comment: Updated question with what i have in place. Would be good to check if the param is available in `AuthorDriver` but for now i just have a `try/catch`

Comment: Firstly, compare the logs in `Logcat` for both Galaxy S1 & Nexus around the statement `setOrientationHint()`. I found the code for AuthorDriver [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/android/author/authordriver.cpp) but it does not say which Android version does it belong to so compare the logs and see if same code gets executed in Nexus also. What do you mean by "our client is running a device with 2.3.3 and they mentioned the problem with screen rotation is ok."? Does the API work fine on their 2.3.3 device?

Comment: what i mentioned about the client... I mean they didn't mind too much that the screen did not rotate on their version 2.3.3 but this was because i was forcefully blocking the rotate call on anything less than SDK 10. But it was always in the back of my mind that its unacceptable and I needed to fix it. So now that it has a try catch around the line i am fairly sure their device will begin rotating the video correctly. It is only this Samsung Galaxy S1 which will not. I have sent off the update and will see whether the rotate fix works.

Comment: Regarding the line around the statement `setOrientationHint()` Nexus running 4.2.2 has no alert at all, if happily runs this and the video is rotated on playback as expected.